# why RoutData.Values["txtName"] throws a nullreference error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have to the following code to access values from `Route.Values`

The `index.cshtml` with input controls and values

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using( Html.BeginForm("Create", "Concepts", FormMethod.Get, null ) )
{
    @Html.Hidden("ghia", new { d="sssd343433333355555%%%%%%%" })    
    <input type="text" name="txtName" value="dummydata1" />
    <input type="text" name="txtsdsdfs&&&&33adada" value="dummydata2" />    
    <input type="submit" value="New" />
}
```

in the `Create.cshtml` when tried to access those values

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@{
    //Routeda
    var p1 = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["txtName"].ToString;        
}

<p>@p1</p>
```

the above throws a `Null Reference` exception in the line:

```
var p1 = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["txtName"].ToString();
```

**My RouteMap is**

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "test1",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{txtName}/{txtsdsdfs&&&&33adada}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Concepts", action = "Create" }
           );
        }
```

why the line throws the exception and how do i fix this?

Comment: Because they are added as query string values, not route values - use `var p1 = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Get("txtName");`

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay im confused, when i set RoutMap it adds those values to ViewContext.RouteData.Values collection right?

Comment: No. I will add an answer with a bit more explanation, although its a little unclear what the purpose of doing this is.

Comment: @StephenMuecke well query string is easy : )  wanted to try alternative approach : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your submit your form, the name/value pairs of the form controls are added as query string values, not route values, because your browser has no knowledge of your routes. In order to access then you can use

```
var p1 = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Get("txtName");
```

The only way to add route values is using server side code, for example

```
@using( Html.BeginForm("Create", "Concepts", new { txtName = "someValue }, FormMethod.Get, null ))
```

would allow you to access the value using `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["txtName"]`

Comment: hmm... how do i add my textbox value to txtName property in routeData object in form header?

Comment: You cant (unless you were to use javascript to change the `action` attribute of the form element before submitting, which would be just plain crazy) - it was just an example to show you that its only possible using server side code.

Comment: cheers mate, but one quick verification,  in the POST methods teh query string is hidden and added to teh message body so even in the POST method i can use above two techniques??

Comment: In a POST, you need to access the `Form` collection (although of course, the correct way to to use a model and post back to a method which has the model as a parameter so your model is bound.

Comment: And its still unclear why you would need that code anyway. If your submitting to a GET method with those parameters, you would initialize a model based on the parameters and pass it back to the view

Comment: i forgot ask, in the typical enterprise apps what kind of information is added to routeData object in the form header?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment

Comment: in a real world application what kind of information is send through routeData object

Comment: I assume you mean the `object routeValues` parameter of `BeginForm()` which will populate the `ViewContext.RouteData` collection. An example might be a page displaying a collection where you have a 'Delete'` button for each item. You might use a form and the add the ID of the item as a route value so that its posted back to `public ActionResult Delete (int ID)` as opposed to adding a hidden input inside the form.